# JavaScript Code Doesn't Execute in Base64'd Document

Tags: javascript, html, base64, execution

I have learned that I can open all kinds of documents as Base64 URLs, as seen in the very last line of this post. So far, I can open an HTML document, but it contains JavaScript, and I cannot execute my function `rr()`, which is called by clicking the **"Create New Form"** button. I am using Firefox 16 and with NoScript installed. As far as I know, I have made it allow `file://` and `data: URLs. But I don't know why I can't execute the function by clicking the button, but I can execute it if I run it from the browser's address bar. What is the problem or likely problems I should check for?

```
<html>
    <title>about:2012-09-04</title>
    <script>
        function rr() {
            var r=document.location;
            //This is to make r stop pointing
            //to the actual document.location object

            r+="";
            r=r.replace("data:text/html;base64,","");
            r=atob(r);
            //r=r.replace(/.+/,"{}")

            r=r.replace(document.title, "about:"+document.getElementById("datetitle").value);
            r="data:text/html;base64,"+btoa(r);

            window.open(r,"_blank");
            document.getElementById("urlnew").value=r;
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form target='_blank' action='http://google.com/search' method='get'>
            <input type='text' name='q' />
            <input type='hidden' name='tbs' value='qdr:d' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <br /><br />
        ____________________________________
        <br />
        Date: <input type="text" id="datetitle" /><br />
        URL: <input type="text" length="25" id="urlnew" /><br />
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:rr()" value="Create New Form" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And base64 encoded:

```
<code>data:text/html;base64,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</code>
```

Comment: base64-encoded data is frequently used for various attacks, like cross site scripting or phishing. Maybe some security feature of the browser gets in your way?